# Creating a Link Between Pages in React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

App.js

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Header />
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="signin" element={<Signin />} />
          </Routes>
          </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Signin.js

```
class Card extends Component {

  render() {    
    return (        
      <Link to="signin">Signin</Link>
    )
  }
}
```

How to move to the sign in page in version 6 of the react router without the Home  appearing,
Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the behavior to be, exactly? You just want to navigate to `"/signin"` when clicking the link in `Card`? What is the issue? What isn't working as expected?

Comment: I want to explain exactly why my link works on my home page while I want my signin component to be displayed on another page

Comment: You are asking why/how the link works? Is this correct? See [Link](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link).

Comment: No, there is no problem with the link. I think it is difficult to define my routes. I am working to see how I can fix it in my own code

Comment: So what is the issue then? What are you trying to do that isn't working?

Comment: First thank you so much attention to my question  ,I understood my fetch api first rendered before signing component that resolved issue by below way very well worked

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would suggest you change the signin endpoint from `signin` to `/signin`.
Secondly, there's an extra closing `</div>` in your code.

You can use `Redirect` here in this way

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Header />
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={} >
                 <Redirect to="/signin" />
               </Route>
              <Route path="/home" element={< Home />} />
              <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin />} />
          </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

For more info [refer here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-set-react-router-default-route-redirect-to-home)

Comment: Thanks for response but Redirect (and redirectTo in useRoutes) was removed

Comment: Follow these links:
1. https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#remove-redirects-inside-switch
2. https://gist.github.com/mjackson/b5748add2795ce7448a366ae8f8ae3bb (last part)

Comment: Thanks for contributed but  Unfortunately can't upvote your answered

Answer (score 1):

when used of `componentWillMount` becouse Executed before rendering and is used root component can used of Routes in this component, like below

```
class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    /**
     codes that fetch from api
    **/ 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Header />
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          </Routes>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

In the component Card that has linked to the signin, must be like below

```
class Card extends Component {

  render() {    
    return (        
      <button>
        {hasProducts ? <nav><Link to="signin">Checkout</Link></nav> : 'Checkout'}
      </button>
    )
  }
}
```

In the class based component when decided used of library `react-router`,
No way that used of `useParams` for path of access current url,
instead of this can use `window.location.pathname`,
also can used of Routes on the `react-router v6` and conditional ternary operator for access current url path, like below

```
class WrappedComponent extends Component {
  render() {
      const pathname = window.location.pathname === current pathname;
    return (
      <>
      { pathname ? 
      <Routes>
          <Route path="signin" element={<Signin />} />
      </Routes>
      :
      <div>
      /**
       codes that return data of api and firstly rendered
      **/
      </div>
      }
      </>
    )
  }
}
```